# How to handle import of multiple functions with same name in NAMESPACE file, when writing R Extensions?

Tags: r

I am making an R package and I am trying to get the NAMESPACE file right. In general my question is: Say that I want to use (import), in my package, two different functions but with the same name, in turn exported by two different packages. How can this be specified in the NAMESPACE file and in the code?

Specifically I get the following warning:

> `Creating a generic function for 'boxplot' from package 'graphics' in package 'affyPLM'`
>
> `Creating a generic function for 'hist' from package 'graphics' in package 'affyPLM'`

I am guessing that this means that the `boxplot` and `hist` methods for the `fitPLM` class are replaced by ones from `graphics`? I also import `affy` but this does not give a warning, although there is a `boxplot` method for the `AffyBatch` class. The thing is, I only use `importFrom(affyPLM, fitPLM)`.

How can I get rid of the warning? I have struggled to find any answer on the web but without success, so if you have any idea or tip, please help me!

Comment: This is coming from affyPLM, rather than your package, so there is nothing to be done about it. It's not a warning but a message. affyPLM says `setMethod(boxplot, ...)` and this causes S4 to create a generic for `boxplot`; you can see this yourself in a fresh R session with just `setClass("A"); setMethod(boxplot, "A", function(x, ...) {})`. It's not clear that this is the question you meant to ask?

Comment: Ok, thanks, this helped me. I agree that it is not really clear in my question, mainly because I did not understand the concept. So basically, affyPLM is just creating a generic for `boxplot` which will be used if the argument of boxplot is of class PLMset? And the message is simply giving this information? Why is this message appearing when I do `library(myPkg)` and not when I do `library(affyPLM)`?

Comment: Yes you're right about the creating a generic / dispatching when the argument is PLMset, and the message giving you that information. As for 'why', I think the answer is 'because', i.e., that's the way it's implemented. It's worth a shout-out to R-devel with a simpler example if at all possible.