# R package needs functions of the same name from two packages

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I have read through numerous posts on this topic and have spend far too much time to try to get it right. So I finally decided to write yet another question on the topic.

What I want is to use the NAMESPACE file with import/importFrom correct. The problem is that I get a warning upon the RCMD check (which is not appreciated on CRAN):

`Warning: replacing previous import by 'gtable::gtable' when loading 'strvalidator'`

It is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8122633/2173340) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12251530) question but none of them make me any wiser.

My package (full code [here](https://github.com/OskarHansson/strvalidator)) use the `gtable` function from both the `gtable` and the `gWidgets` package so the solutions to [only import functions that you use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325867) or [change the order of import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8663239) does not solve the problem. I always use the double colon for the `gtable` functions (i.e. `gtable::gtable` and `gWidgets::gtable`) as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11682901/2173340) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564654/2173340) post.

I use `importFrom` for all functions (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403565)) except for the packages where I use numerous functions (here I use `import` instead. I have tested with `importFrom` but it gives the same warning).

Any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT:
So I will add what I ended up doing as requested by @catastrophic-failure. I think I can't add a proper answer because this question is a duplicate. Instead I add the solution as an edit:

I ended up removing all the importFrom from the NAMESPACE file. The four main packages that I use without :: has import in the NAMESPACE. Other package functions are used with :: and their packages are listed (together with the four main packages) as Imports in the DESCRIPTION file. This approach works (i.e. does not give me any errors), but does not make use of the importFrom.

Comment: You seem to be making trouble for yourself.  Why not just `require(gtable)` and `require(gwidgets)` and call the specific functions via colons?  Or alternatively,  copy the code , with attribution, and include a `my_gtable` function in your package.

Comment: Thanks, that will probably get rid of the warning. But it is the preferred way? I got the impression that `import/importFrom` was encourage over `require` (see [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-August/358754.html)). I am still confused about many things on how to make R packages, so there are plenty of room for improvements...

Comment: Good point; I guess my personal approach would be to consider your situation one in which you can justify using `require` .

Comment: I ended up removing all the `importFrom` from the NAMESPACE file. The four main packages that I use without `::` has  `import` in the NAMESPACE. Other package functions are used with `::` and their packages are listed (together with the four main packages) as `Imports` in the DESCRIPTION file. This approach works (i.e. does not give me any errors), but does not make use of the `importFrom`.

Comment: @OskarHansson Please add your solution as an answer so it's readily visible.

Comment: I find using `::` produces more readable code since you always know where the function comes from. That is also what Hadley recommends in http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html (section "Imports"). The only things I usually import are stuff like `%>%` and the whole assertthat package.